# How to get datasource from Hibernate Configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, datasource, hibernate-mapping

I would like to get a datasource from a hibernate Configuration programmaticaly. Here is the code that I wrote :

```
public static DataSource getDatasource(Configuration configuration){
    ServiceRegistry registry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
    SessionFactoryImpl session = (SessionFactoryImpl)configuration.buildSessionFactory(registry);
    DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl provider = (DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl) session.getConnectionProvider();
    return provider.getDataSource();
}
```

But I got an exception while running the application :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: CONTACTS
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1281)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:155)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:508)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1769)
at com.heavenize.Migrations.getDatasource(Migrations.java:30)
at com.heavenize.Migrations.main(Migrations.java:60)
```

I am performing some database migration and I need the datasource to pass to my migration tool programmaticaly.

It seems that problem come with the fact that `buildSessionFactory` because hibernate is trying to map the entities with the tables in the database.

The property `"hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"` is set to `validate`.

Is there a better way to get the datasource?

Comment: You are right that it is an issue with Hibernate initialization due to `hbm2ddl`, even without your code you would get it. Read the documentation and find the value that does not create neither update neither validate the ddl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you are getting has nothing to do with retrieving the `DataSource`. It is because Hibernate is validating the data model with the database and doesn't find it to be in syncrhonization. You can remove the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property completely, which will then default it to `none` and there won't be any validation.